# HTML+JavaScript Calendar

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

What i have to do to insert calendar into HTML text box? Is there any simple method to add that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.google.lt/search?q=html+javascript+calendar

[No 4](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/) looks promising.

```
var cal1xx = new CalendarPopup("testdiv1");
cal1xx.showNavigationDropdowns();
```

Comment: Appreciate the google nudge, but I added a direct link since the ranking could easily change by tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try out following link

http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/

It has lots of variation of HTML + JS calendars along with source code.

Hope this will help.

Thanks!

Hussain.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Datepicker is a nice choice for simple calendar.check out 
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker